iText7 InvalidOperationException and BadImageFormatException in .NET 8
I've been using iText 7 for about a year and have been using it in my .NET 6 projects.  Since upgrading to .NET 8, when adding a paragraph or table to a document, I get two errors once I hit the line to add the paragraph to a document. Has there been breaking changes in iText7 8.0.5?
Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Reflection.Metadata.dll

PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileStream("C:\\Output\\test.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)));
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

string line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf";
document.Add(new Paragraph(line));
document.Close();

Call Stack
System.BadImageFormatException
  HResult=0x8007000B
  Message=PE image does not have metadata.
  Source=System.Reflection.Metadata
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile) in System.Reflection.Metadata\MetadataReader.cs:line 323

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader.GetMetadataBlock() in PEReader.cs
    System.Reflection.Metadata.PEReaderExtensions.GetMetadataReader(System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader, System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReaderOptions, System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataStringDecoder) in PEReaderExtensions.cs
    System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetAssemblyName(string) in MetadataReader.cs

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: PE image does not have metadata.


Can you provide a stack trace? This could give some clues which assembly was been loaded.

System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=PE image does not have metadata.
Source=System.Reflection.Metadata
StackTrace:
at System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader.GetMetadataBlock() in System.Reflection.PortableExecutable\PEReader.cs:line 217

I edited the original post with the full call stack

Thank you, unfortunately, it does not show the assembly it is trying to load.

@Brad, were you able to solve the problem?
I can't reproduce the issue.
Could you attach the full project to reproduce?
Did you try earlier 8.0 versions? What happens if you comment out 'document.Add(new Paragraph(line));' line of code? Did you try to start a new project from scratch?
